# How to search a column name in all tables in a database in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to search like below:

```
Like '%tax%'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the below

```
Select distinct object_name(object_id), name from sys.columns where name like '%tax%'
```

or

```
select table_name, Column_name from Information_Schema.Columns where Column_Name like '%Tax%'
```